# Android hidden service

Tags: android, android-service, hidden, android-toast

Could someone please help me figurate how to make an app that has no icon and starts at the startup?

I want it to start in every startup and keep running all the time, because I want to Toast the name of the sender each time there's an incoming SMS.

Comment: Will your project is going to have any activity ?

Comment: I think so 'cause I want to read the name of the sender and Toast it

Comment: So, if your project doesnt contain any activity then you can't actually listen incoming SMS using BroadcastReceiver. You can do it only if you are targeting your application to Android OS < 3.0

Comment: You mean I can't run apps without a layout on Android OS > 3.0 ?

Comment: Yes, Please read this blog http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

Comment: I think we're not talking about the same thing. I'm talking about a layout-less app that runs in the background. That's what you was talking about?

Comment: that means there will not be any activity in your project right and that blog clearly states that if your project is not going to have any activity ( GUI ) then it won't run. It will be in stop state all the time.

Comment: Ist there maybe a way to make the app visible at the app drawer and after the user enters for the first time the app hides itself and will make it start every startup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "hidden" as the O/S generally tries to avoid allowing you to hide behavior from the user.  What you want to do is discussed in this question [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android).  That will enable you to launch a service and then by watching for the appropriate intents related to SMS messages you can create the toasts you desire.

Comment: Wrong, since there is no GUI part in the app, it will not run on Android OS > 3.0